# Right way to set up a secondary citus worker

Tags: postgresql, standby, citus

I am experimenting with the postgres-addon citus.
So far I have setup a cluster with one coordinator and three worker nodes.

Now I want to setup a secondary for one of the worker nodes.
So far I have setup streaming replication from that worker node to the fourth (standby) node.

Do I have to add the standby node as secodary now with [add_node](https://docs.citusdata.com/en/stable/develop/api_udf.html?highlight=add_node%20secondary#citus-add-node) and noderole "secondary"?

**citus_add_secondary_node** is better, since you have to define the suiting *primary* node with that command?

Or is it simply enough to setup a fresh database with citus extension and the *add_node/secondary* will turn that node into a secondary with all the data from the worker?

I get the right group-id for the secondary with this command:

```
select * from pg_dist_node;
```